# How to find Date format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am looking to simply find out what is the current Date format that I have in m MYSql Database.  This should be easy but I am not finding the command or function to do this. I simply want to query for date format and have it return what it is currently set at, basically; DD:MM:YY or YYYY:MM:DD or whatever the format currently is set at for a particular DB.

Thank You

Comment: The date format is always Y-m-d

Answer (score 1):

By default, the date format is YYYY-MM-DD. However you can convert any date with the `CONVERT()`-function. Make sure to look this function up.
 You'll have lots of possibilities.